# Why do I keep getting Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x000000B70C8FF360. when using vector?

Tags: c++, exception, memory, vector

Visual studio shows 0 issues found but when program starts, a tab pop up with vector library and points on line 2151 and says

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF90121CF19 in Project2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location
```

I wrote a code that checks vector position (k) with next vector position (k + 1) and if it has the same number it removes position (k)
It should stop checking and removing duplicates after it reaches size of vector but I keep getting the exception error. I tap continue and it works fine but still after every "continue" it shows an exception error. How to stop getting that?

```
void removeDuplicates(vector<int>& nums) {
    int k = 0;
    while (k != nums.size() + 1) {
        vector<int>::iterator iter = nums.begin() + k;
        if (nums.at(k) == nums.at(k + 1)) {
            nums.erase(iter);
        }
        ++k;
    }
}
```

I tried to tap continue and it works fine but still after every "continue" it shows an exception error.
In code I tried to remove arithmetical operators next to "nums.begin()" and inside brackets of "nums.at()" but it didnt help.

Comment: Why `nums.size() + 1`? When `k == nums.size()` you will be out of bounds. Not to mention that you *also* use `k + 1` as index, which will then be *two* elements out of bounds. Perhaps you ment to use `nums.size() - 1` instead?

Comment: I did it so loop works until it done working on after LAST number of vector, so it doesnt stop when int k reaches the size.

Comment: @GlebBespalov -- *How to stop getting that?* -- Your code has bugs.  Fix the bug(s).  This isn't a case where you were promised something that works, you find out it doesn't work, and then think it's something else (other than your code) that's not making the code work.

Comment: You might be surprised to learn that, in C++, if a vector has, say, 5 values, the 5th one does not exist. This is because the values that exist, in a vector of five values, are values #0 through #4. If you used your fingers to count them, you'll get five total. But value #5 does not exist. The last value in a non-empty vector is not `size()`, but `size()-1`.

Comment: Why not a `for` loop? Like `for (unsigned k = 0; k < nums.size() + 1; ++k)` which is equivalent to your current loop. Now it's also much clearer (I think) that you will use an out of bounds index.

Comment: Side note your code will not remove all duplicates even if the indexing was right.  Maybe that's what you need and then look up [std::unique](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) or use std::set to help you out. E.g.  `std::set<int> set{nums.begin(); nums.end();};` followed by `nums = std::vector<int>{set.begin(),set.end()` will do the same thing in time compelxity O(n log n) instead of O(n^2). In both cases you can achieve what you want without even writing an (explicit) loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely you want to check `k < nums.size()` to stay within bounds. You could check `k != nums.size()` but then your loop could do something clever like increment `k` by a bigger number than `1` and skip right over `nums.size()`.

But then you index with `k + 1`, so you probably want `k < nums.size() - 1` as your condition. You may wish to test if the container is empty, and if so, immediately return.

I would suggest that unless you're absolutely required to modify the original, you return a new vector containing these values.

Answer (score 0):

your code tries to remove successive duplicates only, hence the function name is not clear.

You use indexes in the wrong way. The indexes start at 0 and end at  `nums.size() -1`.

check this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom

and if u would define k before the while loop its a for loop without any doubt

Example of a working code.

```
void removeSuccessiveDuplicates(std::vector<int>& nums) {
    if (nums.empty()) return;
    size_t end = nums.size();
    for (size_t k = 0; k < end - 1; ++k) {
        if (nums[k] == nums[k + 1]) {
            for (size_t i=k+1;i<end-1;++i){std::swap(nums[i], nums[i+ 1]);}
            --end;
            --k; // Check the current index again in the next iteration
        }
    }
    nums.resize(end);
}
```

I could have used `std::remove_if` with `std::erase` or used rotate in the current example but I just wanted to emphasize how ur code could be corrected

play with it here https://godbolt.org/z/Pz8orb5qK

Comment: `vector::erase` doesn't reallocate; there are no reallocations in the code. The performance issue here is that each `erase` moves all the subsequent elements down one position.

Comment: Your code will fail if `nums` is empty.